# How to create a user from a file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file called `user.txt` with around one hundred entries that are in this format: `user:password:group:shellToUse`

ex. :

```
martin:pwd123:photo:bash
marc:pwd321:devel:c-shell
...
```

How can I create users by reading the entries in this file with a Bash script?

Also, the home directory of the users must look like `/home/group/user`, and the default `shellToUse` is Bash.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user have the necessary privileges you could use something like the following

```
filename="$1"
while IFS=: read uName pw group shell; do
    shell=${shell:-bash}
    # if shell is the empty string, set $shell to bash
    shell_path=$(which $shell)
    useradd -d /home/$group/$uName $uName -g $group -s $shell_path
    echo -e "$pw\n$pw\n | passwd $uName
done < "$filename"
unset IFS
```

call the script in the following way:
    ./script_name user.txt

and do not forget to make the script executable, i.e.

chmod u+x script_name

as mklement0 suggest, this should speed up the script.

i do not understand the comment about shell=${shell:-bash}

[useradd manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)

[passwd manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html)

Comment: Promising, but you can simplify - and drastically speed up - reading and parsing the input lines with `IFS=: read uName pw group shell`. Also, you're missing `shell=${shell:-bash}`. Please structure your narrative text better.

Comment: what do you suggest by shell=${shell:-bash}?

Comment: `shell=${shell:-bash}` assigns literal 'bash' to variable `$shell` if `$shell` is currently undefined or empty (contains the null string) - this is required to satisfy the OP's requirement that the shell default to `bash`. The `${<varName>:-<defaultValue>}` syntax is an instance of [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe). Since you shouldn't really run as root, a script like this should be invoked with `sudo` which temporarily provides the necessary privileges on a per-command basis.

Answer (score -1):

If you use bash, the pseudo code looks something like this

```
Open file and read lines 
for eachline in lines:
    Split the line using awk. Take hints from  https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/awk-split-string-using-a-delimiter/ 
    use 'adduser' command to create user with password. Take hints from http://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/
```